Hotspot turns off if no internet connection
I am using the hotspot feature in Ubuntu to create a local wifi. This works fine when I have an internet connection. However, in cases when I don't have access to internet the Hotspot turns itself off after a few seconds.
The same thing seems to happen when I use nmcli to create the hotspot.
How do I create a hotspot in ubuntu that doesn't shut down when the internet connection is lost?

Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please mention the OS version you are using.

This is what helps me when I reboot my pc or the wifi issues.
Or you can wrap it into some ping healthchek to rescue connection when internet connection is lost ..
UUID=$(grep uuid /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot | awk -F= '{print $2}')
nmcli con up uuid $UUID

